# ionic capacitor ios splash screen not working

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, splash-screen, capacitor

On android screen, splash screen works.
But when I run it as ios via xcode I only see a black screen.
How to show splash screen in ios?
I put the splash image in the resource folder, and put the image in the splash of assets of the ios app.

Comment: did you use the regenerate resources command to rebuild icons / elements for ios platform ?

Comment: you have to add icons and Splash in your xcode.

Comment: I have added icons and splashes to xcode.

Comment: Even when running ionic cordova resources ios, the splash screen is not visible.